# Find maximum depth of nested parenthesis in a string R code

Tags: r, nested, parentheses

I have a problem to finish this R code. We are given a string having parenthesis like below
     “( ((X)) (((Y))) )”
We need to find the maximum depth of balanced parenthesis, like 4 in above example. Since ‘Y’ is surrounded by 4 balanced parenthesis.

If parenthesis are unbalanced then return -1
My code looks like this:

```
current_max = 0
max = 0
def = function (S){
  n=S
  for (i in nchar(n))
    if (is.element('(',n[i]))
    {
      current_max <- current_max + 1   
    }
  if (current_max > max)
      {
        max <- current_max
      }
  else if (is.element(')',n[i]))
  {
    if (current_max > 0)
    {
      current_max <- current_max - 1
    }
    else
    {
      return -1
    }
  }
  if (current_max != 0)
  {
    return -1
  }
  return (max)
}
```

but when i call function def("(A((B)))") answer should be 2. But every time it shows 0 even when the parenthesis is unbalanced. Im not sure if the code is correct or where is the mistake. Im trying to learn R so be patient with me. Thanks

Comment: I don't think `is.element('(',n[i])` is doing what you think it is doing!  You probably need `substr(n,i,i)=="("`

Comment: So finaly i finished the code. Now it shows if parenthesis is balanced or unbalanced. If it is balanced it shows the max parenthesis, if it is unbalanced it shows -1. Thank you everyone for a big help. I really appreciate it. Here is the final code for everybody who will need to solve this kind of problem:
`sample = function(z)
  {
  y = match( strsplit(z, "")[[1]], c("(", ")"), 0 )
  m <- max(cumsum( c(1, -1)[y] ))
  if((min(cumsum( c(1, -1)[y] ))<0)||(sum( c(1, -1)[y])!=0))
     {
      print(-1)
    }
  else
    {
      print(m)
    }
}`
Just call it like `sample("(A((B)))")`

Comment: @Filip Pittner,  `sample("abc")` should be 0 but gives different answer and multiple warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x <- "( ((X)) (((Y))) )"`, then remove all of the non-parentheses and split into characters...

```
y <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^\\(\\)]", "", x), ""))

y
 [1] "(" "(" "(" ")" ")" "(" "(" "(" ")" ")" ")" ")"
```

and then the maximum nesting is the highest cumulative sum of +1 (for `(`) and -1 (for `)`)...

```
z <- max(cumsum(ifelse(y=="(", 1, -1)))

z
 [1] 4
```

If the parentheses are unbalanced then `sum(ifelse(y=="(", 1, -1)))` will not equal zero.

Comment: A related idea would be to match the individual characters to `(` and `)` with `y = match( strsplit(x, "")[[1]], c("(", ")"), 0 )` then re-code and cumsum `max(cumsum( c(1, -1)[y] ))`

Comment: I tried it but when the parenthesis is unbalanced it shows me the first balanced parenthesis. Like (A)(B)) shows 1 but it should show -1 as B is not balanced. I put it in function so i can call it easily 
    `sample = function(z){`
    `y = match( strsplit(z, "")[[1]], c("(", ")"), 0 )`
    `m <- max(cumsum( c(1, -1)[y] ))`
  `print(m)`
    `}`

Answer (score 0):

Here are three solutions.  They are all vectorized, i.e. the input `x` can be a character vector, and they all handle the case of no parentheses properly.

**1) strapply/proto** `strapply` in the gsubfn packages matches the regular expression given as the second argument running the function `fun` in the proto object `p` which should also be passed to `strapply`. The `pre` function in `p` initializes the calculation for each component of the input `x`. The proto object can be used to retain memory of past matches (here `lev` is the nesting level) allowing counting to be done.  We append an arbitrary character, here `"X"` to each string to ensure that there is always at least one match.  If we knew there were no zero length character string inputs this could be omitted. The `sapply` uses `Max` which takes the maximum of the returned depths or returns -1 if no balance.

```
library(gsubfn) # also pulls in proto

# test input
x <- c("(A((B)))", "((A) ((())) (B))", "abc", "", "(A)((B)", "(A(B)))")


p <- proto(pre = function(.) .$lev <- 0,
           fun = function(., x) .$lev <- .$lev + (x == "(") - (x == ")") )
Max <- function(x) if (tail(x, 1) == 0 && min(x) == 0) max(x) else -1
sapply(strapply(paste(x, "X"), ".", p), Max)
## [1]  3  4  0  0 -1 -1
```

**2) Reduce** This is a base solution.  It makes use of `Max` from (1).

```
fun <- function(lev, char) lev + (char == "(") - (char == ")")
sapply(x, function(x) Max(Reduce(fun, init = 0, unlist(strsplit(x, "")), acc = TRUE)))


    (A((B))) ((A) ((())) (B))              abc                  
           3                4                0                0 
     (A)((B)          (A(B))) 
          -1               -1
```

**3) strapply/list**  Another possibility is to extract the parentheses and return with +1 or -1 for `(` and `)` using `strapply` with a replacement list.  Then run `cumsum` and `Max` (from above) over that.

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$sapply(strapply(x, "[()]", list("(" = +1, ")" = -1), empty = 0), ~ Max(cumsum(x)))
## [1]  3  4  0  0 -1 -1
```

Comment: Its good too but not enought. There is a problem if parenthesis is unbalanced. Like (A)((B) or (A(B))) it should print -1 but it will print the first correct parenthesis even if it is unbalanced

Comment: That's just a matter of replacing `max` with a function `Max` that returns the maximum or -1 depending on whether or not there is balance.  Have made that change.

Comment: Thank you. At least i have 2 solutions for this problem.

Comment: Have added 3rd approach.